# automate a downloading of csv file from a random url with Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, url, download

Using Pandas in Python, I want to download a csv file from [this](https://www.jpx.co.jp/markets/derivatives/participant-volume/archives-01.html) website but the download link contains some random characters so I want to know how to automate it.

It's a financial trading data which gets updated everyday. The csv file I want to download is the one in the red square in the top row. Everyday, a new row is added on the top and I want to automate a downloading of this csv.

[image]

My plan was to automatically import the csv to pandas in Python, by dynamically creating url string using the date of the day. The example of a url looks like this:

`https://www.jpx.co.jp/markets/derivatives/participant-volume/nlsgeu000004vd5b-att/20200731_volume_by_participant_whole_day.csv`

And here is my Python script.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
day = dt.today()
date = str(day.year) + '{:02d}'.format(day.month) + '{:02d}'.format(day.day)
url = 'https://www.jpx.co.jp/markets/derivatives/participant-volume/nlsgeu000004vd5b-att/%s_volume_by_participant_whole_day_J-NET.csv' %date
# Followed by pandas...
```

The problem is, a part of this url(`nlsgeu000004vgi7-att`) is always a random sequence of characters and I cannot really dynamically query it. For example, that of 7/30, this part is `nlsgeu000004vd5b-att`. At least, I don't know what the rule is to generate this string.

Is there any way to correctly point to this kind of partially-random url? I thought of some workarounds but don't have any idea how to actually implement them. It would be great if you could help me! As long as I can automatically download the csv, any way is fine!

- using regular expressions
- using scraper such as BeautifulSoup to get the url of whatever the csv in the top row

Comment: Your BeautifulSoup idea is a good one. 
No better place to start than the docs! https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you don't know how the url is generated you'll need to scrape the page to find it. Here's a quick example using BeautifulSoup with a regular expression filter to find the first link on that page that includes `volume_by_participant_whole_day.csv` in the url:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.jpx.co.jp"
data = requests.get(f"{base_url}/markets/derivatives/participant-volume/archives-01.html")
parsed = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
link = parsed.find("a", href=re.compile("volume_by_participant_whole_day.csv"))
path = link["href"]
print(f"{base_url}{path}")
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. I will use use this solution. By the way why do you need `re.compile` to pass to the `href`?

Comment: `re.compile` creates a regular expression object, BeautifulSoup uses that to filter the results to elements with an `href` value that matches the regex. Using a regular expression allows filtering on a partial match, which is needed in this case since the full url path (including the unique identifier) isn't known.

See the docs for more info:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#a-regular-expression

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#the-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 0):

I would scrape the website as you suggested. It seems like it would be very easy to do this (as long as these elements are not dynamically generated using javascript) and would remove possible future issues you could get with regex if you assume the url pattern incorrectly:

1. Use GET request to pull html from page (use [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/))
2. Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation) to extract the url you want

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code this will directly fetch link of that particular excel file. I did not used any regex, my answer is based on the position of that element, so you can just get the link by running it.

before running the code make sure you have requests and BeautifulSoup modules

if not these are install instructions

```
# for requests module
pip install requests

# for beautifulsoup module
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

BS Script

```
# Imports
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# Requesting and extracting html code
html_source = requests.get('https://www.jpx.co.jp/markets/derivatives/participant-volume/archives-01.html').text

# converting html to bs4 object
soup = bs(html_source, 'html.parser')

# finding all the table rows columns
trs = soup.find_all('tr')

# selecting 3rd row
x = [i for i in trs[2]]

# selecting 4th cell and then 2nd item(1st item is the pdf one)
y = [i for i in x[7]][2]

excel_file_link = y.get('href')

print(excel_file_link)
```

Comment: fantastic! thank you very much. Your solution is also great, as long as the position doesn't change, even thought the url rule slightly changes it still works.